# URL Alias Preventing a Pattern on Vocabulary

Tags: uri

I am trying to setup a replacement pattern with URL Alias on a vocabulary called 'Media Categories' using the pattern 'media/[term:name]'.  However whenever I try and generate the aliases this vocabulary is left unchanged.  I have tried changing the pattern to something else like 'edia/[term:name]' and that works, it seems as though it is reserving the 'media/[term:name]' somewhere.

I have tried flushing the cache, deleting the vocabulary and terms and adding them again, however I have still had no success.  The only option I have had so far is to manually enter the url alias.

Has anyone come up against something like this before?  All I can think of is that 'media/[term:name]' is reserved somewhere...

Comment: You may want to check for a duplicate alias.

Comment: I think I have tracked it down to view's because I have a view defined for say 'media/orders' then URL Alias won't generate a alias.  For some reason I wouldn't have thought a view path would block URL Alias from doing its thing.  I am going to test disabling all my views, generating the aliases, then re-enabling the views to see if that cures it.

----
Just to add, this only seems to happen with taxonomy terms.  I have defined paths for nodes in views - yet URL Alias seems fine with generating and alias for them.

Comment: Apologies, as my account is new, I had to wait 8 hours before I could answer my question.  Done now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to Digital Fire, I started checking for other alias conflicts, which I found in my defined views.  The problem I had initially was that the URL alias was working with views, however clicking on the link / taxonomy term took you too the default drupal view.

So in order to get the term with an alias working with view's I realised that in the view path use the original link to the taxonomy term instead of the url alias.

Hopefully that makes sense and might help someone else out.